# Calling content with url php

Tags: php

```
$cat_name = secure_sql($_GET['cat']);

if ( ! empty ($cat_name))
{
    $cats = $cat_id = get_catid($cat_name); 
    
    
    $category_name = get_catname($cat_name);
    $list_subcats = list_subcategories($cat_id, '');
}
else
```

The above code url part;

newvideos.php?cat=name

When I type it works, but when I type normal newvideos.php it doesn't work. How can I run newvideos.php Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

You're passing a parameter through the GET method. And this is done by adding a question mark ? after the URL.

There only way to do as you want, that is to let only the URL whitout the rest part, then you can send the parameter using the POST method but then replace the GET by POST in the PHP top script line. And of course, you need to update as well the HTML.

The other way is to fix the value of name to be always a constant like cat, but not sure you are looking to do that.

Comment: Okay, thanks i understand it